# jQM select pre-render?

Tags: jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I am using a grouped select to achive my desired interface...two questions:

1. I need to intercept the DOM before actually showing the list of selects because there is text in the injected SPAN that jQM adds which I want to further enhance by wrapping some minor text in  tags for better visual acuity.
2. The select controls will not seem to go full width given this code.

   ```
   <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
   ```

Any ideas on how I might accomplish these tasks in 1.4???

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can tell jQuery Mobile to not auto-initialize any widget with a specific tag name, id or a class.

Place the code below in head, after jQuery.js and before jQuery Mobile.

```
<head>
  <!-- jQuery.js -->
  <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      $.mobile.keepNative = ".native"; /* jQM 1.4 */
    });
  </script>
  <!-- jQM.js -->
</head>
```

Now, add class `native` to `select`, to stop JQM from enhancing it on startup.

Do whatever changes you want and then enhance it manually.

```
$("select").removeClass("native").selectmenu();
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/DWLAf/)**