# how to resize and position a list of items in Jquery Mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap, jquery-mobile-select

I have found in jquery mobile this code to select multiple items.

```
<div class="ui-field-contain" >
    <label for="select-custom-19">Multiple:</label>
    <select name="select-custom-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" >
        <option>Choose options</option>
        <option value="1"> 1st </option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">2nd </option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected"> 3rd </option>
        <option value="4">4th </option>

    </select>

</div>
```

I  have found  a way to reduce the size of the list box like this :

```
<select data-mini="true" data-inline="true" name="select-custom-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" >
```

It's smaller but not the size I would like (I would like even smaller) - how to do it?  
 I have tried : `style="width:5%;"` but it doesn't work.

Also I would like to fix this list box in a specific position. For example, when I want to place a button in a position in the screen I use this, and it works fine :

```
<button style="position: absolute; top:470px; left:310px;" onclick="stopMusic()" type="button"></button>
```

but

```
 <select style="position: absolute; top:470px; left:310px;" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" name="select-custom-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" >
```

doesn't work.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Good catch. The native select will be wrapped by the framework, but the `data-wrapper-class` won't work (it seems to be an open TODO which hasn't be never fully implemented for the `selectmenu` by the JQM team).
The keypoint here is to find the parent wrapper `div` which has class `ui-select` and style that one.

You can either:

- set a custom class for the container element
- add a custom class after the `select` widget creation

Here is an example which shows both options:

```js
$(document).on("selectmenucreate", "#select-custom-19", function(e, ui) {
  $(e.target).parent().addClass("my-select-class");
});
```

```css
.my-select-container-class .ui-select {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
  width: 100px !important;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.my-select-class.ui-select .ui-btn {
  background-color: aliceblue !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div class="ui-field-contain my-select-container-class">
        <label for="select-custom-19">Multiple:</label>
        <select name="select-custom-19" id="select-custom-19" data-mini="true" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
          <option>Choose options</option>
          <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
          <option value="2" selected="selected">The 2nd Option</option>
          <option value="3" selected="selected">The 3rd Option</option>
          <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Another option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851624/jqm-select-pre-render/20853755#20853755 (First part).

Comment: @Omar class native  gives me another kind of box ,  it  is smaller true but I would like the same list format. Plus how can I change the position?

Comment: @deblocker it doesn't do what I really need. The alice blue box stays the same size, and I would like it smaller. Plus how can I put this box in an other position?
Or may be I am not sure how to proceed... in your example there is no class in the select widget as you told me to do

Comment: Hello @deblocker well, I know I am not an expert.

Comment: Hello @deblocker well,  I would like to have this select box even smaller. and to put it in a position I want.
or, I know I am not an expert, but how should I Write the code?
the first 2 paragraphs are to put between <style></style> or only the 2nd ?one?
and inside the select widger i should write 
 class = $(e.target).parent().addClass("my-select-class")

Comment: @  deblocker , below this is how I wrote your code

Comment: @ubi: I am sorry, can't debug incomplete code. Simply copy & paste my full working example.

Comment: @deblocker This is what I did, copy paste... at least can you tell me if the structure I wrote below is the good way?

Answer (score -1):

This is how I wrote what you said, jquery mobile etc is written in the head... It's not working still have the same big box choice in the same position

```
  <html>
    <style>
    
    .my-select-container-class .ui-select {
      border: 1px solid red !important;
      width: 100px !important;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }
    .my-select-class.ui-select .ui-btn {
      background-color: red !important;
    }
    </style>
    
    <body>
    
    <div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-field-contain my-select-container-class" >
        <label for="select-custom-19">Multiple:</label>
        <select   name="select-custom-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" >
            <option>Choose options</option>
            <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">The 2nd Option</option>
            <option value="3" selected="selected">The 3rd Option</option>
            <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
    
        </select>
    
    </div> 
    </div>
   
</body> 
    </html>
```